# Get value from Web Api Controller in ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, pdftron

I have a web api controller GET api method in which I call an external REST service to fetch data. I want to show a piece of data (a property from my data model class to hold the external web service data) on asp.net page. The api controller calls a method of a repository class library where I fetch the data from the external REST service and return in my web api controller.

I call my web api contoller get api method in a javascript on the ASP.NET page where I use the PDF Tron web viewer control.

```
<script src="settings.js"></script>
```

I don't want to use Session (though Session is not available, workarounds are available to use Session) as it would make my REST api stateful.

Please advise on what options are available to fetch data from a web api controller in asp.net page.

```
//Settings.js code

window.WebViewerUniversalInstance.model.set(
{     
    documentUrl: "/api/Document/?type=XOD&docno=101",    
    //serverUrl: "../html5/annotationHandler.php",    //server script for handling annotations
    annotationUser: new PDFTron.WebViewer.User("Guest", false),
    currentPageNumber: 0,
    pageCount: 0,
    zoomLevel: 0,
    fitMode: PDFTron.WebViewer.FitMode.Zoom,
    layoutMode: PDFTron.WebViewer.LayoutMode.SinglePage,
    toolMode: '',
    rotation: 0,
    webViewerLibPath: 'lib/', //URL path to the WebViewer lib folder
    webViewerOptions: { //extra WebViewer options
        silverlightOptions: {
            enableAnnotations: false //disable annotations if silverlight is loaded. 
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean exactly by "I want to show a piece of data on asp.net page.". You mention WebViewer, but that only displays XOD or PDF files, so it is unclear how that relates to the rest of your question.

Comment: @Ryan : As in the PDF Tron viewer, I call the ASP.NET web api as : documentUrl: "/api/Document/?type=XOD&docno=101". This web api call fetches other data apart from the actual XOD document also. I want to display the other data fetched from the web api call on the ASP.NET page. Please let me know if this clarifies your query.

Comment: To clarify, documentUrl is not part of the WebViewer API, so I take it that parameter is what you use to get your extra data. It is still unclear how WebViewer has anything to do with your question. You might have a better chance at getting your asp.net question answered if you remove the WebViewer parts. Or, if the question is about WebViewer, remove the unrelated ASP.Net parts.

Comment: documentUrl: "/api/Document/?type=XOD&docno=101" is a part of web viewer control, using which the web viewer control fetches the document. The same web api called in the documentUrl of the web viewer control fetches the document and other related data for the document. My question is how to get the data that is being fetched by the web api called in the viewer control. However, I have removed the 'pdftron' tag from my question.

Comment: I seem, you appear to be using an old version of WebViewer (1.8.2) and I would recommend updating to the latest version at https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/download.html.
Regardless, it sounds like you're trying to request additional data aside from the XOD in the same request. It would probably be easier to make a separate request for the additional data so that the XOD can just be passed directly to WebViewer. That is you are overloading the documentUrl parameter, and should instead make your custom request another way.

Comment: @Ryan : I am already using the latest PDFTron Web Viewer v2.2.2 that I had downloaded from PDFTron website. I won't like to make duplciate calls and hit the database multiple times to fetch the results once for fetching the document and then again for fetching document attributes. However, if the result set from calling the web api in PDFTron 'documentUrl' can't serve this, is there any other possible way to execute the web api call in the settings.js file and then bind the document to PDFTron web Viewer. I am not downloading the document physically, using byte array from webapi to fetch doc.

Comment: @Ryan : Any update on this further?

Comment: @Ryan : I have used the PDFTron code sample as descriobed here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfnet-webviewer/VKVnTmu90II

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentUrl option is just a helper method, and cannot be overloaded like you are trying to do.

If you want to optimize to a single server call, then you would do this manually your self, just as you would normally make any server request using ASP.Net.

So in response to

```
/api/Document/?type=XOD&docno=10
```

your server could return some sort of response like below.

```
{
  xodurl: url,
  metadata1: data1,
  metadata2: data2
}
```

You would then pass the url parameter to the WebViewer documentUrl parameter.